# most efficient method to extract key: value pairs from a pandas column and use the keys as columns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large data set, 50000 or so csv's containing about 40000 lines, that I need to read into dataframes, extract the key: value pairs and use them as columns/values in the same dataframe. The excerpt below is a single column of my pandas dataframe:

```
column 
'this is my string of data., you can:  parse me now, but:  you will never find me'
'this is some crazy data., where are:  you at today?, you can:  never find me, but:  this is fun.' 
'this is more crazy than ever, where are:, you can:  not parse me, strange:  stuff'
```

How can I extract just the key: value pairs that match the following criteria? I am trying to do this in the most efficient method due to the iteration over multiple files.

```
between two commas
must contain a colon
two spaces after the colon
any character to include spaces
```

With an expected output of expanding the keys to columns and values in the columns:

```
you can          but                      where are      strange     <==columns
parse me now     you will never find me   NONE           NONE
never find me    this is fun              you at today?  NONE
not parse me     NONE                     NONE           stuff
```

Updated visual of data.

```
                                 1
  0                               
0  subject                     NaN
  strange sub                AcDe1
  strange name               i001$
  stuff and things           86753
  newby id                      09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extractall` to get all the key value pairs in long format, and transform it so the keys goes as the column headers, assuming the original column name is `col` here:

```
(df.col.str.extractall("([^,]+?):(?:\s{2}([^,]+))?")
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
   .unstack(level=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors or just the result is not correct?

Comment: The unstack doesnt produce any results for some reason, but when I try and drop a level with out hte unstack, it prints key  value  columns. No errors that I see.

Comment: For the `set_index`, make sure `append` parameter is set to true and there is a `[1]` after to select the value column.

Comment: It is exactly how you have it in your example. hmm

Comment: What is your `pd.__version__`? It seems to work on `0.19.1`.

Comment: Currently on 0.19.2, testing a few things. It might be the way I am using it.

Comment: Just tested on `0.19.2`, works as well. My python version is 3.5.1 btw.

Comment: As is mine. I posted a visual of what my print of your command minus the .unstack(level=1). Everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: That looks correct to me, if you have two levels index, and one column at this point. It's weird to me a simple unstack will fail.

Comment: Could it be that I have about 80 unique items that would be turned into rows and not all my data has all of them?

Comment: In that case you should get None under the missing field or missing a row but not nothing.